# String format error

Tags: c#

I've coded a uptime to my application and it's just displaying random numbers?

the program time is this code

```
public static DateTime TimeStarted { get; set; }

    public static void Time(string[] args)
    {
        //set start time
        Program.TimeStarted = DateTime.Now;
    }
```

and then this is a class to display the uptime

```
case "uptime":
{
    TimeSpan sinceStarted = (TimeSpan)(DateTime.Now - Program.TimeStarted);
    double secondsRunning = sinceStarted.TotalSeconds;
    string message = string.Format("{0} Days, {1} hours, and {2} minutes", sinceStarted.Days, sinceStarted.Hours, sinceStarted.Minutes);
    Session.SendData(UserAlertModernComposer.Compose("Stats", message));
    return true;
}
```

its currently saying 735096 days 7 hours and 34 minutes when the uptime is around 20 minutes,

Comment: Check, please, "Program.TimeStarted" value; you may test it just bychaniging "message = Program.TimeStarted.ToString()"; formatting itself seems being correct one.

Comment: where are you calling the Time method?

Comment: TimeSpan bit is okay, you sure Program.TimeStarted is what you think it is.

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to keep yourself this value. It is already available in the [Process.StartTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.starttime.aspx) property. You only need to get an handle to  the current process

```
Process p = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
TimeSpan sinceStarted = (TimeSpan)(DateTime.Now - p.StartTime);
string message = string.Format("{0} Days, {1} hours, and {2} minutes", 
          sinceStarted.Days, sinceStarted.Hours, sinceStarted.Minutes);
```

Comment: ive set that as the console title is there a way i can make it update automaticly? (refresh) say.. every 5-10 seconds?

Comment: use a timer, set the interval property to your like and update the form title in the Timer.Tick event. [Here docs and an example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.Timer.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the [Stopwatch class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) for your purposes. Its in the System.Diagnostics namespace and should be better suited for you.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopWatch.Start();
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
        stopWatch.Stop();
        // Get the elapsed time as a TimeSpan value.
        TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;

        // Format and display the TimeSpan value.
        string elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}",
            ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds,
            ts.Milliseconds / 10);
        Console.WriteLine("RunTime " + elapsedTime);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment you are never calling your Time method. **Which means TimeStarted will have the DateTime.MinValue**. DateTime.MinValue is equivalent to `01/01/0001 00:00:00`. Hence the result you are getting.

What you need to do is to write the following line in **program.cs**

```
Program.TimeStarted = DateTime.Now;
```

Rest is fine